# XMLHttpRequest error on http request to google api in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, flutter-web

When sending http requests to a google api (directions api) with http package I get this error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 963:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                       <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1685:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 557:7                                         [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1530:7                                             <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37309:58                              <fn>


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:54316/dart_sdk.js:5093:12)
    at Error._throw (http://localhost:54316/dart_sdk.js:20399:18)
    at Error.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:54316/dart_sdk.js:20396:18)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54316/dart_sdk.js:40921:18)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54316/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54316/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:54316/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

Here is my http request:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'constants.dart';

class Directions {
  Future<void> getRouteInfo() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=$googleAPIKey');

    final response = await http.post(url);
    print(response.statusCode);

    final relevantBody = json.decode(response.body)['routes'][0]['legs'][0];
  }
}
```

My google account has billing active. The API key is working with other google apis in the same Flutter app and getting no errors. And when I copy & paste the url from the request to the browser I get the correct result. When I try to print the response status I can't because the error is thrown before and there is no response.

I know there is one solution that involves disabling web security, but this only works locally, I need this to work in production. Is this CORS related?

Comment: May be these API doesnt work from local host

Comment: Check the error from the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/14329886) to solve the issue. Basically you need to use a proxy to then add a CORS header to send back to your browser. I created one with Heroku.